# import python module and alias submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does python 3.7 offer a way to import modules and alias only the submodules?
Suppose I have a module named `module` with a submodule `ridiculously_long_submodule_name` that I'd like to alias with `short_submodule`

Is there a way to alias just the submodule so I can call it via `module.short_submodule`?
I tried the obvious `from module import ridiculously_long_submodule_name as module.short_submodule` resulting in a syntax error.
I'd really like to avoid importing it without the main module name in front because of confusion issues with the rest of my code

Comment: Why not just `from module import ridiculously_long_submodule_name as short_submodule` ?

Comment: I have other modules that use similar names, which is why I'd rather have the module in front

Comment: Not possible as far as I know.

Comment: OK, how about: `from module import ridiculously_long_submodule_name as module_short_submodule`?

Comment: Will have to do as a workaround I guess. I thought there would be a way to "naturally" alias the submodule. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no dedicated syntax for aliasing `module.ridiculously_long_submodule_name` as `module.short_submodule`, and while you could mess with the module's attributes to do it manually, it'd be a bad idea.

Aliases set with import `as` are supposed to be local to the scope where the import happens, to avoid name conflicts, but setting `module.short_submodule` to the submodule you want would be a global change. All code in the program would see it, because unless you get really crazy with `__getattribute__`, there's no such thing as an object "locally" having an attribute.

Even code in `module` would see an unexpected new global variable. That can cause really nasty conflicts if the writers of `module` ever want to use the `short_submodule` name, but even without that happening, mucking with other libraries like this is going to confuse people who have to maintain or debug your code, including the you of 12 months from now.

Just do `import module.ridiculously_long_submodule_name as submod`. Don't try to put a `module.` prefix on the alias.

Comment: If you need some other code to see the hacked module name, you can use something like: `sys.modules['sklearn.preprocessing.label'] = sys.modules['sklearn.preprocessing._label']`.  ... where .label is the name you want and ._label is the name that is already successfully imported.  But this is a hack in the a strong jury-rigging sense of the word.  Hopefully whoever is in a similar situation can get it to work just enough to move along to some better solution.